# Multiplication: uint vs float

Tags: c++

Why are the two following result different? The result of the following multiplication should be an integer anyway.

```
uint16_t test = 500.00 * 128.51;
std::cout << test << std::endl; ----> 64254
```

but

```
float test = 500.00 * 128.51;
std::cout << test << std::endl; ----> 64255
```

Comment: What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic
: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html

Comment: This is really basic, any textbook should explain the difference between integer and float.

Comment: @MitchWheat It's much more basic than that. He doesn't even understand what an integer is.

Comment: Integers are whole numbers, they don't have fractions.

Comment: @Barmar: The OP did not claim that integers have fractions.

Comment: @Barmar But the exact result of `500.00 * 128.51` is in fact an integer.

Comment: Oh, now I see what he's asking about.

Comment: To complete the linked duplicate,  500.00 * 128.51 is actually slightly smaller than 64255 (as 128.51 cannot be accurately represented in binary FP). When casting to an integral type, decimals are discarded, so your 64254.99999... becomes 64254. OTOH, when keeping it as a double, you preserve the 64254.9999..., and the default cout behavior is to *round* at some decimal position when printing, so when displaying it you see it just as 64255.

Comment: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/03ba7c2125ecbdd7 there it is

Comment: @MatteoItalia: I've actually re-opened as the general purpose dupe doesn't seem all that useful to be quite honest, particularly with such a subtle cause (intermediate error carried over to an otherwise would-be exact result). I think your comment would be great as an answer here.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: I was dubious as well about the dupe, it can be useful as an intro to "why FP is inexact", but single cases are probably best handled on their own, especially if, as in this case, everything gets mixed up with truncation and rounding behavior of the stream. I'll move that comment to an answer.

Comment: @MatteoItalia: Yep nice one

Answer (score 6):

(moving from a comment)

To complete the [previously linked duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken), 500.00 * 128.51 is actually slightly smaller than 64255 (as 128.51 cannot be accurately represented in binary FP).

When casting to an integral type, decimals are discarded (the value is *truncated*), so your 64254.99999... becomes 64254.

OTOH, when keeping it as a `double`, you preserve the 64254.9999..., and the default `ostream::operator<<` behavior is to round at some decimal position when printing, so when displaying it you see it just as 64255.

Answer (score 3):

> The result of the following multiplication doesn't have decimals.

Maybe it doesn't in base 10 (decimal), but computers don't work in base 10. They work in base 2, and in base 2 128.51 has more <strike>decimals</strike> fractional digits than can be stored in the `float` (or, actually, *any* similar format — it would require infinite places, much like trying to write out 1/3 in decimal).

This error carries through so, although mathematically 64255 is a whole number, the result of your multiplication is closer to 64254.9999999999927240.

`std::cout` is automatically rounding this up by default (because it knows that this kind of thing happens); however, during conversion to `uint16_t`, a dumb truncation happens instead, resulting in the incorrect 64254.

With some I/O manipulator magic, we can see this more clearly:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

int main()
{
    std::cout << std::fixed << std::setprecision(16) << (500.00 * 128.51) << std::endl;
    std::cout << uint16_t(500.00 * 128.51) << std::endl;
}

// 64254.9999999999927240
// 64254
```

#### ([live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bb3649624566fea5))

Comment: (I just picked 16 at random; when it's not 1.19am you would select a sensible value for this, using _facts_)

Comment: 16 is actually correct, a double has 53 bits of mantissa, which correspond to 53/log2(10) = 15.95 decimal digits of precision.

Comment: @MatteoItalia: Running out to buy a lottery ticket right now

Comment: In seriousness, it _did_ feel familiar ^_^

Comment: Secret trick: I actually remember by heart that it's 53 bits/15.something decimal digits, and that they are linked by a logarithm; I just threw everything in the mix until the values came out right. (it's 2.30 am here after all)

Comment: Might I suggest include outputting `128.51` with fixed precision as well?

Comment: @CraigYoung: Yep go ahead